# What would be the most efficient way of performing text substitution on this collection?

Tags: java, regex, performance

Imagine you have a `List<String>` collection, which can contain tens of thousands of Strings.
If some of them are in the format of:

```
"This is ${0}, he likes ${1},${2} ... ${n}"
```

What would be the most efficient way ( performance-wise ) to transform a string like the one above to:

```
"This is %1, he likes %2,%3 ... %n"
```

Note that the % way starts from 1. Here's my solution:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
...
String str = "I am ${0}. He is ${1}";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\\$\\{(\\d+)\\}");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str)
while(mat.find()) {
   str = mat.replaceFirst("%"+(Integer.parseInt(mat.group(1))+1))
   mat = pat.matcher(str);
}
System.out.println(str);
```

I hope it's valid Java code, I just wrote it now in a GroovyConsole. 
I'm interested in more efficient solutions, since I'm thinking that applying so many regex substitutions on so many strings might be too slow. The end code will run as Java code not Groovy code, I just used Groovy for quick prototyping :)

Comment: Your solution looks good to me.  Algorithmically it's as efficient as possible and I doubt that any other searching method will be notably faster than regular expressions.

Comment: Algorithmically it is <b>not</b> as efficient as possible.  The replaceFirst method is O(length of string), so if you do many replacements on a long string the time taken is potentially quadratic.  An efficient algorithm for this is linear.

Comment: I would have preferred using `replaceAll`, if there wasn't the increment captured group thing.

Comment: @btilly: ah yes, my mistake, I overlooked the reassignment to `mat`; if the OP called `while(mat.find(end))` where end starts at zero and is updated with `mat.end(1)` instead of replacing mat, then it is linear.  Good catch.

Comment: @Geo: I'm sorry for missing the increment captured group thing.

Comment: @maerics: Starting the match from where you left off is helpful, but not sufficient for long strings.  The call to replaceAll is still O(length of the string).  To make it more efficient you'd need to make a stringBuffer, and stuff pieces of the string and replacement, then construct the final string at the end.  If you have short strings and few replacements, this strategy is probably going to be a net loss, but for long strings with many replacements it is a big win.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test
{
  static final Pattern PH_Pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\d++)\\}");

  static String changePlaceholders(String orig)
  {
    Matcher m = PH_Pattern.matcher(orig);
    if (m.find())
    {
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(orig.length());
      do {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
        sb.append("%").append(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)) + 1);
      } while (m.find());
      m.appendTail(sb);
      return sb.toString();
    }
    return orig;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    String s = "I am ${0}. He is ${1}";
    System.out.printf("before: %s%nafter:  %s%n", s, changePlaceholders(s));
  }
}
```

**[test it at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/jAXP8)**

`appendReplacement()` performs two major functions: it appends whatever text lay between the previous match and the current one; and it parses the replacement string for group references and inserts the captured text in their place.  We don't need the second function, so we bypass it by feeding it an empty replacement string.  Then we call StringBuffer's `append()` method ourselves with the generated replacement text.

In Java 7, this API will be opened up a bit more, making further optimizations possible.  The `appendReplacement()` functionality will be broken out into separate methods, and we'll be able to use StringBuilders instead of StringBuffers (StringBuilder didn't exist yet when Pattern/Matcher were introduced in JDK 1.4).

But probably the most effective optimization is compiling the Pattern once and saving it in a `static final` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should begin your match from the last checked index of the string instead of the first index at each iterative step.  As btilly alludes in a comment, your solution is O(n^2) where it should be O(n).  To avoid unnecessary string copying, use a StringBuilder instead:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("I am ${0}. He is ${1}");
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\\$\\{(\\d+)\\}");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);
int lastIdx = 0;
while (mat.find(lastIdx)) {
    String group = mat.group(1);
    str.replace(mat.start(1), mat.end(1), "%"+(Integer.parseInt(group)+1));
    lastIdx = mat.start(1);
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Code is untested so there might be some off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be more efficient to use `appendReplacement` since then you aren't making a ton of new String objects and the search doesn't resume from the beginning each time.

```
 String str = "I am ${0}. He is ${1}";
 Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\d+)\\}");
 Matcher mat = pat.matcher(str);

 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(str.length());

 while (mat.find()) {
    mat.appendReplacement(sb, "" + Integer.parseInt(mat.group(1)));
 }
 mat.appendTail(sb);

 System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Prints:

> I am 0. He is 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String str = "I am ${0}. He is ${1}";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(\\d+)\\}");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(string);
StringBuffer output = new StringBuilder(string.length());
while(mat.find()) {
   m.appendReplacement(output, "%"+(Integer.parseInt(mat.group(1))+1));
}
mat.appendTail(output);
System.out.println(output);
```

(Copied mainly from the Javadoc, with the added transformation from the question.)
I think this is really O(n).

Comment: Obviously I'm not typing fast enough, as takteek already gave this solution while I was typing.